# VideoView full screen even after fixed values in xml (Android 2.2)

Tags: fullscreen, android-videoview, android-2.2-froyo

I am facing a strange situation in which the VideoView that I have put in XML layout has fixed width/height, but when same runs on Android tablet running 2.2 of screen resolution (460*800), the video always goes to full screen, and the other views of the same XML overlaps the video.

I do not want video to go to full screen, I want it to be of fixed width/height!

Following is the XML layout, any help is welcome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgRight"
    android:layout_width="267px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBottom"
    android:layout_width="533px"
    android:layout_height="153px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgRight" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="533px"
    android:layout_height="307px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap videoview with a relative layout. Set fixed px values to relative layout and change videoview dimensions with fill_parent:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="533px"
    android:layout_height="153px" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer  [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)
Examples of supported video encoding parameters.

```
                  SD (Low quality)SD (High quality)  HD (Not available on all devices)

Video resolution    176 x 144 px    480 x 360 px    1280 x 720 px
```

Video resolution Lower quality = 176 x 144 px Higher quality = 480 x 360 px

Answer (score 0):

I later realized that Android 2.2 can only play video in full screen mode..